# Python code to convert excel to CSV - condition works in PYCHARM but fails as invalid syntax in shell python

Tags: python, excel, csv, apache-spark

I have couple of excel sheets which are to be converted as csv but am running into errors with invalid syntax error. Am trying to fetch only contentes where row count is more than 3.
this is my code

```
def convert_to_csv(excel_file, input_dir, output_dir):
    """Convert an excel file to a CSV file by removing irrelevant data"""
    try:
        sheet = read_excel(excel_file)
    except UnicodeDecodeError:
        print 'File %s is possibly corrupt. Please check again.' % (excel_file)
        sys.exit(1)
    row_num = sheet.get_highest_row()  # Number of rows
    col_num = sheet.get_highest_column()  # Number of columns
    all_rows = []
    # Loop through rows and columns
    for row in range(row_num):
        row_values = []
        for column in range(col_num):
            # Get cell element
            cell = sheet.cell(row=row, column=column)
            # Ignore empty cells
            if cell.value is not None:
                if type(cell.value) == int or type(cell.value) == float:
                    # String encoding not applicable for integers and floating point numbers
                    row_values.append(cell.value)
                else:
                    # Encode strings into ISO-8859-1 format to preserve content of cell
                    row_values.append(cell.value.encode("iso-8859-1").strip())
            else:
                row_values.append('')
        # Append rows only having more than three values each
        if len(set(row_values)-{''}) > 3:
            # print row_values
            all_rows.append(row_values)
    # Saving the data to a csv extension with the same name as the given excel file
    output_path = os.path.join(output_dir, excel_file.split('.')[0] + '.csv')
    with open(output_path, 'wb') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerows(all_rows[1:])
    print 'File %s saved to %s ' % (excel_file, output_path)
```

am looping through multiple excel sheets and in one particular sheet am having some unwanted data at the tail which I want to remove.

getting this error

```
19/11/12 03:13:33 WARN SparkConf: The configuration key 'spark.yarn.applicationMaster.waitTries' has been deprecated as of Spark 1.3 and and may be removed in the future. Please use the new key 'spark.yarn.am.waitTime' instead.
  File "/u/kim/excel_to_csv.py", line 49
    if len(set(row_values)-{''}) > 3:
                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

this works on Pycharm but fails in Terminal is there I'm trying to fetch all the rows where the contents in the row is greater than 3 ,any work around?

Comment: what if you use set(['']) instead of {''} ?

Comment: Na coming up like this File "/u/kimbrahi/excel_to_csv.py", line 49, in convert_to_csv
    if len(set(row_values)-['']) > 3:
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'set' and 'list'

Comment: no, I meant set(['']). I write a tentative answer below

Comment: If you have a different behavior in Pycharm and in terminal, I would suspect different versions of Python used in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line:

```
if len(set(row_values)-{''}) > 3:
```

to this one:

```
len(set(row_values)-set([''])) > 3:
```

I do not know why it fails on the terminal. Check you python versions. The syntax above works when I call from python 2.7 and 3.6.8 as:

```
 python test.py
```

Comment: it works without error but is not serving the purpose :(

Comment: @IrthizaKhan have you thought of using numpy's .read_excel() method and then manipulating the data?

Comment: the python am using is 2.3

Answer (score 0):

```
import openpyxl
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Pt
from docx.enum.style import WD_STYLE
print "lists".decode("utf-8")
a=raw_input()
cid=[]
cid.append(0)
for i in a.split(' '):
    i=int(i)
    if not i in cid:
        cid.append(i)
cid.sort()
print cid
document = Document()
document.add_paragraph("Рўйхат".decode("utf-8")).size = Pt(14)
style = document.styles['Normal']
font = style.font
font.name = 'Times New Roman'
font.size = Pt(12)
qator=len(cid)
table = document.add_table(qator, 6)
sheet = openpyxl.load_workbook('РЎЙХАТ.xlsx'.decode("utf-8")).active
pp=0
for x,i in enumerate(cid):
    print(i)
    r0 = sheet.cell(row=i+1, column=2).value
    r1 = sheet.cell(row=i+1, column=3).value
    r2 = sheet.cell(row=i+1, column=4).value
    r3 = sheet.cell(row=i+1, column=5).value
    r4 = sheet.cell(row=i+1, column=6).value
    heading_cells = table.rows[pp].cells
    heading_cells[0].text = str(x)
    heading_cells[1].text = r0
    heading_cells[2].text = r1
    heading_cells[3].text = r2
    heading_cells[4].text = r3
    heading_cells[5].text = r4
    pp=pp+1
document.save('РЎЙХАТ.docx'.decode("utf-8"))

# A special list compilation developed by @apiuz
# Writes data from Excel to word
# All businesses and organizations are free to use``

#xlsx to docx
```